# Duplicate Form Field Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm attempting to duplicate a form input entry. Is it possible specify a specific input and output field using ID or class with Javascript?

In this example I am trying to duplicate the entry from ***id1*** and have it output to ***uniqueid***. However, all fields are affected. How do I specify the ID?

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="id1" name="" value="" />
<input type="text" id="id2" name="" value="" />
<input type="text" id="uniqueid" value="">
</form>
```

```
var $unique = $('input[type="text"]').mousemove(function(){
$unique.val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: See jQuery's [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your wires are a bit crossed here. You can select an element by it's ID using the `#` selector.

Let's make this a bit more legible by separating it out:

```js
var $id1 = $("#id1");         //Store id1 input
var $unique = $("#uniqueid"); //Store uniqueid input

$id1.mousemove(function() {   //On mousemove event of id1
  $unique.val($(this).val()); //Set unique's value to id1's value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="id1" name="" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="id2" name="" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="uniqueid" value="">
</form>
```

As [d4nyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594508/duplicate-form-field-inputs/44594551#comment76176881_44594551) mentions in the comments below, if you simply want to update the `uniqueid` field any time `id1` changes, then you should change your `.mousemove()` to be `.keyup()` instead.

Comment: I also wouldn't use the `mousemove` event. Use an `onchange` event instead.

Comment: That change would be entirely based on assumption, as OP hasn't specified his intentions. Furthermore, `onchange` is not a jQuery event (it's `.change()`), and it only fires when exiting the input. A more accurate event would likely be `.keyup()`.

Comment: Thank you both for your help and advice.

Comment: `.keyup()` works. The only reason I'd use `change()` is that if you have any other code updating this field, you want it to also trigger the sync function.